# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in url of image Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

When I am writing the url for the image,
I am not able to run the server. And if I remove the url, I won't be able to save the image..

```
url(r'^item/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Please suggest a solution, I tried a couple of solutions from SO, but couldn't solve.

Comment: @Abdulafaja I went through the link but didn't understand

Comment: You should explain your question what about it you didn't understand, that is the answer.

Comment: how can I import Settings.MEDIA_ROOT.. I tried importing as from Settings import MEDIA_ROOT.. it didn't work.. There is no problem in the Views methods

Comment: Thats a completely different question, if you have another question you should consider asking a new question with what you have tried and researched.

Comment: @Sayse i am really sorry i am not able to explain myself I am new to Django.. but this url pattern worked for me earlier, now it is not working.. and the solutions i went through told to import the methods from views separately... but i am not using views in this particular url

Comment: show your full urls.py file

Comment: I have had this problem with some imported packages.  The syntax used is old so now it needs to use the following url for specifying static. `]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)' and need to set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in the settings file with import of settings.